# How to remove small rounded rectangular box inside the bottom navigation bar?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, bottomnavigationview

I have made a bottom navigation bar and it has a small rectangular box inside it. i have searched everywhere but could not find the solution. I have even gone with the code many times if have accidentally added those, but i couldn't find a single one.

[image]

here are some code that might help you.

mainActivity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();

        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch (item.getItemId()){

                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_inbox:
                        fragment = new InboxFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_cart:
                        fragment = new CartFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_profile:
                        fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_more:
                        fragment = new MoreFragment();
                        break;
                }

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
                return true;

            }
        });
    }
```

activityMain,xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        app:itemRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:itemIconSize="30dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/item_selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/item_selector"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
        />
```

item_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="@color/red" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:color="@color/grey"/>
    <item
        android:color="@color/nav"/>
</selector>
```

I have tried every thing I could but I'm not able to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>` to your colors.xml.

Then, add `app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@color/transparent"` to the `BottomNavigationView` on your layout.